# What is the default behavior of child component re-rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple parent - child component structure and want to know why Parent component re-rendering causes the child components to render again, Is it default behavior? and how to prevent it?

Below is my code snippet-

```js
import "./App.css";
import Library from "./library/Library";
import { useState } from "react";
import LibraryParent from "./library/LibraryParent";

function App() {
  const [name, setname] = useState("Ikigai");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* <Library name="around" /> */}
      <LibraryParent name={name} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(name);
          setname(name === "Ikigai" ? "around" : "Ikigai");
        }}
      >
        re-render
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import Library from "./Library";

function LibraryParent({ name }) {
  console.log("LibraryParent", name);
  return (
    <>
      <Library />
      <Library />
    </>
  );
}

export default LibraryParent;
```

```js
import React from "react";
function Library() {
  console.log("Library");
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <p>Library component</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Library;
```

Every button press is giving me this -
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if a parent re-renders, all of its children will re-render too, by default.

If you ever use class components, note that class components have a [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) method that can be implemented for a component to determine for itself whether it needs to re-render or not. Class components also extend [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), which does *not* re-render even if its parent changes, as long as its state and props haven't changed.

With functional components, you can prevent a child from re-rendering by memoizing the element. For example, if your `App` was a bit more complicated (say it could re-render for another reason), and you want `LibraryParent` to only re-render if `name` changes, you could do:

```
function App() {
  const [name, setname] = useState("Ikigai");
  const libraryParent = useMemo(() => <LibraryParent name={name} />, [name]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {libraryParent}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(name);
          setname(name === "Ikigai" ? "around" : "Ikigai");
        }}
      >
        re-render
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Since Library components don't look to depend on anything at all, they could be memoized too:

```
function LibraryParent({ name }) {
  console.log("LibraryParent", name);
  const lib1 = useMemo(() => <Library />, []);
  const lib2 = useMemo(() => <Library />, []);
  return (
    <>
      {lib1}
      {lib2}
    </>
  );
}
```

And so on - you can follow that sort of pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed while using connect of react-redux with child Library component for some state, it prevented the re-rendering by default while useSelector doesnt.

So the whole functional component way of react has this behavior?